# ImageButton open link in new page within Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the below Image Button which resides in a Repeater:

```
<asp:ImageButton PostBackUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VesselId", "getattachment.do?VesselId={0}") %>' CausesValidation="false" ID="insurancestatus" runat="server"/>
```

So every time the user clicked on the button they were shown their attachment.

The requirement has since changed, and the attachment must open on a new page so I added the following to the Repeaters `ItemDataBound` event:

```
ImageButton imagebuttonInsurance = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("insuranceStatus");
            imagebuttonInsurance.OnClientClick = String.Format("aspnetForm.target = '_blank'; return true()");
```

Now when I click on the image it does open another page but it just reloads the previous page on the new page. I tried removing the `PostBackUrl` and wiring up the following click event:

```
protected void insurancestatus_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Vessel vessel = (Vessel)e.Item.DataItem;
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Secure/getattachment.do?VesselId={0}", vessel.VesselId));
}
```

But I couldn't get a handle on the item so cannot use the VesselId for the link, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Check if `return false;` instead works.

Comment: You seem to be posting a lot of code reciting "vessels". Are you working on something to do with submarines?

Comment: Sorry @generalexception that is classified

Comment: Must be government agent.

Comment: I have alternative suggest with simple html+image, instead of asp control and postback thing, you are interested , then i can post answer ( i mean you are open of other solution than asp:imagebutton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second method, but use the command argument property like:

```
 <asp:imagebutton runat=server...... commandargument='<%# Eval("vesselid") %>' />
```

then:

```
protected void insurancestatus_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string vesselId = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;
   Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Secure/getattachment.do?VesselId={0}", vesselId)); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm being daft, why not just create a normal hyperlink? i.e. <a href="secure/gettachment.do?VesselId="<% Eval("vesselId")%>" target="_blank"><img src="some image"></a>